# Finding gcd of real numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know how to find gcd of integers 
I can find the positive common divisors of given integers then can choose the greatest common divisor or using The Euclidean algorithm
Can I find gcd of two rational numbers?
What about irrational numbers?

Comment: How would you define a divisor of, say $\frac12$?

Comment: In order to talk about the greatest common divisor one needs a definition of divisibility (i.e. some way of telling a divisor from a non-divisor).

Comment: Can I do it like (0.5,3.5)=0.5(1,7)=0.5?

Comment: @John Doe Divisors of 0.5 , 0.1,0.2,0.25,0.5 maybe?

Comment: Again, it really depends on what you want "divisibility" to mean in this context. For natural numbers, the concept of divisibility I feel to be pretty natural. I have trouble thinking of an interesting notion of divisibility for irrational numbers.

Comment: @user529392 the issue is, where do you stop. For example, 0.05 could be thought of as a divisor too. Or 0.025. And so on

Answer (score 3):

The Euclidean algorithm will find the gcd of two **commeasurable** real numbers, otherwise the algorithm will never stop. Euclid originally gave his algorithm in his *Elements* Book 7 for "magnitudes" and Book 10 for positive integers. The algorithm will stop for two rationals because you can always get a common denominator for them. The Wikipedia article [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) has much more detailed information if you are interested in knowing more.

Comment: Thank you I will check that

Answer (score 1):

I studied about gcd and lcm of rational numbers in my school.

As @Ianskey has pointed out─ In order to talk about the greatest common divisor one needs a definition of divisibility (i.e. some way of telling a divisor from a non-divisor). My authors started with following definition of divisibility.

> If two rational numbers $\frac{a}{c}$ and $\frac{b}{d}$ satisfy the following equality for some integer $m$,
>   $$\frac{a}{c}=m \times \frac{b}{d}$$
>   then we say $\frac{a}{c}$ is divisible by $\frac{b}{d}$.

$\frac{a}{c}$ is the multiple and $\frac{b}{d}$ is the divisor.

Now see, imagining $\frac{a}{c}$ and $\frac{b}{d}$ are in reduced form, $m=\frac{a}{c} \div \frac{b}{d} = \frac{a}{c} \times \frac{d}{b}$ is an integer **if and only if**─

1. $a$ is a multiple of $b$ and
2. $d$ is a multiple of $c$.

From the above two points are the following definitions of gcd and lcm of two rational numbers.

$$gcd(\frac{x}{y},\frac{g}{h}) = \frac{gcd(x,g)}{lcm(y,h)}$$

$$lcm(\frac{x}{y},\frac{g}{h}) = \frac{lcm(x,g)}{gcd(y,h)}$$

---

I do not know about the irrational part.

**Note**: Each of $a, b, c, d, x,y,g$ and $h$  is an integer.